# Primitive types and IN operator

Tags: groovy, collections

I use the `in` operator in groovy very much. But now I found an odd behavior.
See the following script.

```
int x = 1
long y = 1

println "x == y           " + (x == y)           // true
println "x == new Long(y) " + (x == new Long(y)) // true
println "x in [y]         " + (x in [y])         // false Why?
println "[y].contains(x)  " + [y].contains(x)    // false Why?
```

The `in` operator or the `contains()` return `false`, although the two numbers are equal. But why?

I've learned that a collection can't contain primitive types, but `x == new Long(y)` is true.

Comment: Because x is int and y is long

Comment: @dsharew You are right, it is not the same object. But 'x == y' returns true.

Comment: yeah interesting point but it is not. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why it is not working?**
Because `x` is `int` and `y` is `long`.

**Why (x == y) returns true?**
The `==` operator uses type casting behind so  `(x == y)` is same as:

```
(x == (int)y)
```

---

When you create a list in groovy using `[]` syntax groovy uses the `ArrayList` class behind. So the `in` and `contains()` method returns depend on the `contains()` method implementaion:

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return indexOf(o) >= 0;
    }
```

As you can see it calls `indexOf` method:

```
 public int indexOf(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (elementData[i]==null)
                    return i;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

and the `indexOf` method actually depends on the equals method implementation of the object passed.

So  when you say `[y].contains(x)` or `x in [y]` it will use `Integer`'s `equals()` method implementation:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Integer) {
            return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

As you can see it will return `false` if you are not passing an `int` regardless of the actual value.

if say  `[x].contains(y)` or `y in [x]` it will use `Long`'s equals method implementation:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Long) {
            return value == ((Long)obj).longValue();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

which again returns `false` if the argument is not instance of `long` regardless of the value.

As further example this code should return false:

```
int x = 1
long y = 1

x.equals(y)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, it is all correct. But for me, it is a ugly pitfall. In my daily work for example, if I check if a project-id (long) with "projectId in [1, 2, 3]" I will get always false. I have to write "projectId in [1l, 2l, 3l]".

Comment: you welcome. yeah all you have to do is you have to know what you are putting into your list in other words make your list to contain homegenous  type. So if your list contains integers during search you have to do ```list.contains((int)param)``` if your list contains longs during search you have to do ```list.contains((long)param)```